# ChromeOS crouton Ubuntu Unity return with noexec error on 128GB SD card

Tags: unity, sd-card, chromebook, chroot, crouton

I just installed Ubuntu Unity chroot on my HP 19"5' chromebook in dev mode and everything went fine until I tried to run it.

The SD is formatted to ext4 and already has Linux installed, but when i run

```
sudo sh /media/removable/SD\ Card/bin/enter-chroot
```

```
sudo sh enter-chroot
```

```
sudo sh startunity
```

or

```
startunity
```

it returns:

```
sh: 0: Refusing to exec startunity from noexec mount; see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/security/noexec_shell_scripts.md
```

The web address didn't help.

Please note I am quite inexperienced with Linux so I might have missed something very obvious.

Comment: `noexec mount` seems pretty obvious. and do visit see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/security/noexec_shell_scripts.md

Comment: all the site has on it is a link to the readme for crouton

Comment: Here is a full installation guide https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466